# Error: TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/index.html

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-2.2

I'm stuck with this error message, tried different solutions from here, but nothing helps. When I run the server I get this error message: **TemplateDoesNotExist at /app/index.html**

[My app structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Q4BM.png)

settings.py in **contactform:** I add these 2 lines in 'DIRS', but didn't help

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app'
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app', 'templates', 'app'),
 ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: you must use `index.html` instead of `app/index.html`

Comment: So true! Many thanks it works like a magic

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your structure from:
 `<PROJECT>/<APP>/templates/template.html` 
to 
`<PROJECT>/<APP>/templates/<APP>/template.html`